# How to extract data from this API? HttpRequest, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, httprequest

How can i extract the data? I need the circuitName, date, raceName, round, season and time

[image]

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;

xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
  
        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        var yourData = json.MRData; 

 
        document.getElementById('playlist').innerHTML = yourData;

    }
};

xhr.open("GET", "http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/next.json", true);
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Please add JSON instead of picture.

Comment: dude @HassanImam , this is the json http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/next.json

Comment: The name of the variable `json` is not correct. The content will be an actual object and not JSON.

Comment: [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Use this `const {Circuit: {circuitName}, date, raceName, round, season, time} = obj.MRData.RaceTable.Races[0]`

Answer (score -2):

You can use `.map` to use the array of races and return an object that folllow your model for each races:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;

xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
  
    const json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    const { MRData: data } = json; 

    // show the json in HTML
    document.getElementById('playlist').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
    
    // log circuitName, date, raceName, round, season and time
    const { Races: races } = data.RaceTable
    
    const extractList = races.map(({ 
      Circuit: circuit, 
      date,
      raceName,
      round,
      season,
      time,
    }) => ({
      circuitName: circuit.circuitName,
      date,
      raceName,
      round,
      season,
      time,      
    }))
    console.log(extractList)

  }
};

xhr.open("GET", "http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/next.json", true);
xhr.send();
```

```html
<pre id="playlist"></pre>
```

**Note**

to render the JSON in HTML, you should **stringify** the object using [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) otherwise the `Object.prototype.toString` method while serialize it to this string: `[Object object]`

Comment: _"you MUST **stringify** the object"_ - `JSON.stringify()` is not relevant for the solution. Where's the explanation for `extractList`?

Comment: Explanation of .map ? I have added some text to explain what I did.